# Why does this function cast an int argument to a volatile pointer and immediately dereferences it?

Tags: c

I just want to know what below function is doing

```
static int myfunc(int val)
{
    return *(volatile int *)val;
}
```

Comment: Setting aside the `volatile` and `static` keywords for the moment, it casts `val` to a pointer-to-an-int and then dereferences that pointer to return the pointed-to `int`.  This will cause a crash for most inputs.

Comment: I found this in some working code.

Comment: There are much better ways of achieving that sort of thing that are far less fragile.

Comment: @NateChandler Doesn't it result it undefined behaviour on invalid input, which may be a crash? But it could work perfectly well, with perfectly defined behaviour, if the calling function is using it correctly.

Comment: If it does not cause a crash (segmentation fault), then `val` was obtained by casting a pointer-to-an-int to an `int`.  It will still crash "for must inputs".

Comment: Maybe the code is `int* val` and `int val` is a typo.

Comment: @Dukeling I agree with you that it will _always_ cause undefined behavior, and that's the most correct thing to say about it.  "Most of the time," though, it will cause a crash.

Comment: Its not a pointer,its a value

Comment: @Chinna  What was the working code?  A normal application?  Device driver?  Firmware?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If *val* is a pointer when you pass it to this function, it makes sure that the value pointed by this pointer is read and returned to the caller.

I suspect this might be a trick for embedded devices, where sometimes the operation of reading a value at an address has some effect on the hardware.
For instance, reading from an hardware FIFO will pop the read value from the FIFO.

Marking here the pointer as *volatile* make the compiler *not* optimize the read if it detects that the value is not used.

Example:

```
#define FIFO_ADDRESS 0x800050

static int myfunc(int val)
{
    return *(volatile int *)val; // the address *will* be read
}

static int bad( int val )
{
    return *(int*)val; // might be optimized to nop()  
                       // by the compiler if the value 
                       // is not used by the caller
}

int main(){
   bad( FIFO_ADDRESS );    // could be NOP since return value is not used

   myfunc( FIFO_ADDRESS ); // *WILL* perform a READ operation on the FIFO, 
                           // even though the result is not used, because 
                           // of the volatile keyword

}
```

Note that I would do it differently, probably with a smartly named macro:

```
#define FORCE_INT_PTR_READ( address ) *(volatile int *)address
```

Could you give us an example of usage in your case?

Comment: I'd be more inclined to have something like `#define FIFO_ADDRESS (int volatile *)(0x800050)` and use `val = *FIFO_ADDRESS` or `*FIFO_ADDRESS = val`

Comment: I wonder why people still prefer macros to inline functions in many cases.

Comment: @Constantius Sometimes, compilers for embedded devices lag behind what is normal for other systems.  As an example, I was stuck with a non-ANSI C compiler into the late 90's with one system.

Comment: @Constantius: the olc cl30 compiler I use for the TI DSPs don't like inlines, I even found out that the inlining of a function sometimes depends on where it is located in the C file (!). So yeah... sometimes we're better off with macros, which I'm 100% sure will be inlined.

Comment: @MPD thanks for comments. So I'll be better off with inlines in case I program for popular platform?

Comment: @Constantius DSP and embedded programming is a specialized, niche thing.  Very often, C gets written in a particular way to get the resulting ASM the developer wants for the target.  The cl30 compiler mentioned above was weird.  If you are on a normal platform, stick with the specs and write clear code.  Inline functions are much more manageable than macros.

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be trying to confuse the optimiser (and possibly the user). It is taking an integer, treating it as a pointer to an integer, and dereferencing it. The 'volatile' ensures that the optimiser will generate code for that dereference at that point and won't let the optimiser omit the fetch from memory. This is usually used for accessing memory mapped hardware registers,

Answer (score 3):

It does the following:

- Passes a signed integer to a function.
- Converts the contents of the signed integer to a pointer. This doesn't make sense, since pointers cannot be signed. Formally, this is also not well-defined behavior and anything can happen.
- The volatile keyword suggests that the contents of `val` should equal to a physical hardware address. When reading from such addresses, the volatile keyword is necessary, since the hardware register's contents may change at any time.
- It takes the contents of that address and treats it as int, which is then returned.
- `static` means that the function has local scope.

Please note that if the target OS uses virtual addressing (such as a PC), the OS will just give you a slap on the fingers should you attempt to run this code.

All in all, this is poorly written code, which is neither safe, well-defined nor portable. You won't gain any valuable knowledge by staring at it.

Answer (score 0):

It casts `val` to a pointer and returns it's value. Calls to `myfunc()` will work only if thy look like 
    int i, j;

```
i = 10;
j = myfunc( (int)&i )`
```

That should set j to 10

**BUT** it won't work on 64bit systems where `sizeof(int *)` is 8 and thus larger then `sizeof(int)` or on some old systems with `sizeof(int) == 2`

Comment: Arguably one might imagine 64-bit ABI where `sizeof(int) == 8`. In general `intptr_t`, if available, is better choice.